# He seems to be doing/feeling a lot better

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

Let's say I'm talking to my brother when we see a friend who we haven't seen in a while and who we know is/has been struggling with depression but when we see him he seems to be in a very good mood. What would be natural to say to my brother about the friend:

> He seems to be doing a lot better.

Or

> He seems to be feeling a lot better.

?

Answer (score 1):

"*He seems to be **feeling** a lot better*" is better for this situation.

"*He seems to be **doing** a lot better*" is the natural way to refer to someone who appears to be recovering from depression. It takes a holistic view, looking at his behaviour, relationships, work life, friendships, and personal interests, as well as his emotional state.

"*He seems to be **feeling** a lot better*" refers only to the appearance of a person's emotional state. This gives little information in terms of whether a depressed person is recovering from the illness. Why so? Depressed people have good days and bad days, and this may be a good day for him. Depressed people also learn how to put on a happy face so their friends, family and coworkers don't feel bad about them or treat them differently.

So in your case, if you see someone who has been struggling with depression and they appear to be in a good mood, "*He seems to be feeling better*" is the better choice, and understand it doesn't imply anything else about his depression.

Even better would be, "*He seems to be in a good mood*".

Answer (score 0):

"He seems to be doing a lot better" is a more natural way of refering to someone's general life situation. "Feeling a lot better" is better suited for when someone's recovering from an illness.

Comment: True, but depression is an illness (or often conceived as such), so...

Comment: @legatrix The expressions are largely interchangeable, to be honest. In this particular case I would use the first one.

Comment: I might say that a person who had been suffering from depression was feeling a lot better today, but I would say he was doing a lot better if he had got a job, started looking after himself properly, not sleeping all the time, engaging with professional help, etc.

Comment: You don't know how he feels, so if you say he is feeling better, you are imagining what it is like to be him.  If you say he is doing better, you are judging from his appearance and manner.

Comment: Feeling better and doing better are worlds apart in terms of depression. This isn't a sore ankle, where the two are largely synonymous. Even "in a good mood" is worlds apart from "feeling better".